# Проверить наличие значения в столбце meta_value в таблице wp_usersmeta. (WordPress)

Tags: sql, wordpress

В моей таблице wp_usermeta будут храниться номера телефонов пользователей. И при регистрации юзера мне нужно будет делать проверку на то, не существует ли уже в БД регистрируемый номер.

Быстрый гуглинг не дал ответов на то, как это сделать и я решил написать сюда, потому что сильно ограничен во времени.

Я понимаю что нужно будет использовать объект $wpdb. И это единственное что я понимаю.. Поэтому подскажите пожалуйста какой метод для $wpdb использовать, и что вводить в качестве аргумента для поиска номера телефона в wp_usermeta.

Comment: Не нужен тебе wpdb. См https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_userdata

Comment: Да, так будет намного проще) Спасибо тебе, добрый человек ^_^

Comment: С этой функцией не получилось разобраться, она вроде не подходит для моей задачи, хоть и с первого взгляда кажется что подходит. Но я нашёл другую функцию - https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_users. Вот она уже работает так как надо

Comment: Можно и get_users, можно  и другие варианты. Я о том, что   wpdb - это последнее, что надо рассматривать. Его надо использовать только в том случае, если нет более стандартных решений или они по каким-то причинам не устраивают (например создают ощутимую нагрузку).

Answer (score 0):

Можно было использовать WordPress функцию `get_users()`.

В коде это может выглядеть так:

```
$match = get_users(array(
    'meta_key' => 'phone', 
    'meta_value' => $phone // +79998887766
))
if (!empty($match)) {
    ...                    // добавление ошибки номера телефона
}
```